# Bing Ads api only returning data for the first keyword in my request

Tags: php, bing-api

I am looking to get cpc and other data for a large dataset of keywords. However, when I send the request to the api, I am only receiving data back for the first keyword in the `Keywords` array.You will note from the second image below that the `EstimatedBids` data object for the words delivery, pizza, insurance, and lawyer are null. If I, say, put the keyword 'lawyer' first in the array, I will get data for lawyer and nothing for the rest.

**My Code:**

```
$keywords = array('flowers', 'delivery', 'pizza', 'insurance', 'lawyer'); // example array for this question
$proxy = ClientProxy::ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId($wsdl, null, null, $DeveloperToken, $AccountId, $CustomerId, $AccessToken); //no $UserName & $Password

$matchTypes = array (MatchType::Exact);
$keywordAndMatchTypes = array();
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keywordAndMatchType = new KeywordAndMatchType();
        $keywordAndMatchType->KeywordText = $keyword;
        $keywordAndMatchType->MatchTypes = $matchTypes;
        array_push($keywordAndMatchTypes, $keywordAndMatchType);
}

$request_cpc = new GetEstimatedBidByKeywordsRequest();
$request_cpc->Keywords = $keywordAndMatchTypes;

$response_cpc = $proxy->GetService()->GetEstimatedBidByKeywords($request_cpc)->KeywordEstimatedBids;
```

**My Request:**

[image: Bing Ads API Request]

**My Response:**

[image: Bing Ads API Response]

What needs to change so that I can get that data for all of the keywords? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future googlers, I solved my problem by instantiating the `$matchTypes` array in the `foreach` loop. In other words, I changed this old code:

```
$matchTypes = array (MatchType::Exact);
$keywordAndMatchTypes = array();
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keywordAndMatchType = new KeywordAndMatchType();
        $keywordAndMatchType->KeywordText = $keyword;
        $keywordAndMatchType->MatchTypes = $matchTypes;
        array_push($keywordAndMatchTypes, $keywordAndMatchType);
}
```

Into this new code:

```
$keywordAndMatchTypes = array();
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keywordAndMatchType = new KeywordAndMatchType();
        $matchTypes = array (MatchType::Exact);
        $keywordAndMatchType->KeywordText = $keyword;
        $keywordAndMatchType->MatchTypes = $matchTypes;
        array_push($keywordAndMatchTypes, $keywordAndMatchType);
}
```

For some reason, the `$matchTypes` array has to be instantiated each time.